# Hide Excel's Pivot Table Field List

Tags: pivot-table, win32com, xlwings

I have an excel file and created a pivot table in the same using win32com.client library but when opening this excel file it has the PiVotTable Fields tab in the sheet below :

Manually it can closed by clicking on **Field List** option in excel below : Does anyone know how to do in the python library directly using win32com or xlwings. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you are looking for, which is the same for both win32com and Xlwings, is; 
`ShowPivotTableFieldList`

This is a code sample using in win32com
Setting it to `False` disables.

```
from win32com.client import DispatchEx

xlfile = r'C:\Temp\pivot-table.xlsx'

excel = DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(xlfile)
ws = wb.Worksheets('Pivot_Table')

ws.Parent.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False  # Disable

wb.SaveAs(r'F=C:\Temp\pivot-table.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

For Xlwings;

```
import xlwings as xw

xlfile = r'C:\Temp\pivot-table.xlsx'

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(xlfile)
    ws = wb.sheets['Pivot_Table']

    ws.api.Parent.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False  # Disable

    wb.save(r'F=C:\Temp\pivot-table.xlsx')
```